# Как сделать активный таб, сразу при переходе на странчику React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

У меня есть приложение не React с помощью react-router.
У меня есть страничка с пользователями. При клике на пользователя меня перекидывает на страничку http://localhost:3000/users/1
[image: Страничка юзера]

Как можно реализовать переход стразу на активный таб, чтоб при клике на юзера сразу активировался первый таб "albums" И строка адрессная была http://localhost:3000/users/1/albums и уже по этому адрессу будет прогружены альбомы конкретного пользователя.
Вот мой код

```
<>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Header />}>
                <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
                <Route path="users/:id" element={<UserInfo />}>
                    <Route path="albums" element={<Albums />} />
                    <Route path="todos" element={< Todos />} />
                    <Route path="posts" element={< UserPosts />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </>
```

Вот компонент Табов

```
    const TabsBlock = () => {
    return (
        <div className={classes['tabs-wrapper']}>
            <ul className={classes['tabs-block']}>
                <li><NavLink to="albums">Albums</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="todos">Todos</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="posts">Posts</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Пожалуйста подскажите как при переходе на пользователя чтобы сразу подтягивался активный таб АЛБУМС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз вам нужно иметь активный таб, почему нельзя сразу переводить на profile/1/tab, а не на profile/1/, и просто отказаться от ненужного роута. Но если вы по какой-то причине не можете это сделать, и вам необходимо как-то из UserInfo перейти в какой-то tab-page, то вы можете использовать **useNavigate** в UserInfo и просто редиректить пользователя на нужный вам tab. Но это немного напоминает костыль.